# Switch statement not working as expected c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to make a program that picks a different discount depending on what status the user is and how many days they are staying at a hotel, but my switch statement isn't working at all. I've tried using breaks to see where it fails, but I have had no luck.

```
private void BtnCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //declaring variables
    double ratePerDay, preDiscountCost, totalCost;
    string customerStatus = (txtCustomerStatus.Text);

    //getting input from text boxes
    int days = int.Parse(txtDays.Text);
    ratePerDay = double.Parse(txtRatePerDay.Text);

    //initializing discount variable
    double discount = 0;
    //if statement to tell which discount should be applied if any.
    if (days <= 3)
        switch (customerStatus)
        {
            case "Gold":
                discount = 15 / 100;
                break;
            case "Platinum":
                discount = 20 / 100;
                break;
            default:
                discount = 0;
                break;
        }
    else if (days >= 4)    
        switch (customerStatus)
        {
            case "Gold":
                discount = 25 / 100;
                break;
            case "Platinum":
                discount = 30 / 100;
                break;
            default:
                discount = 0;
                break;
        }
    else
    { 
        discount = 0;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean, the statement isn't working? Are you getting unexpected results? Is this event handler never being hit?

Comment: The discount isn't changing when i enter Gold or Platinum into the txtCustromerStatus Textbox.

Comment: probably it got an error because of this "}"

Comment: Is it perhaps because you're performing integer division? `15 / 100` will be `0.15`, which, represented as an integer will be `0`. This _integer result_ will then be cast to a double and assigned to `discount`.

Comment: So I can't get decimals out of a switch statement? Any recommendations on getting around this problem?

Comment: add `m` like `discount = 30m / 100m;` and change double to decimal

Comment: @N.Alcuino double, not decimal.

Comment: This is nothing to do with the switch statement at all. C# will evaluate the right side of an expression first, and then perform any implicit cast available to convert the result to the left side type. Everything on the right side of your expression is integer (`15 / 100`), so the fractional result of the calculation is discarded, leaving you with `0`. You need to change it to `15 / 100.0` to cause the right side part to perform the calculation as a `double`. It's explained in the question yours is a duplicate of.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I searched for at least a day and could not find a duplicate.

Comment: @TravisThomas - don't worry about it. You didn't know your bug was related to integer division and truncation, so you couldn't have found the appropriate question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John said, you're performing integer division in the gold and platinum blocks. `15 / 100` is integer division (because `15` is an `int` literal and `100` is an `int` literal) and results in `0`. Assignment to `double` only happens after the division happens.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation

At least one of the divisors must be a `double` for you to get your expected result. You can try dividing `15.0 / 100` or `15 / 100.0` or `15.0 / 100.0` or `(double)15 / 100` or `15 / (double)100`.